# Coinjoined coins are not available on another instance of wallet

Tags: seed, coinjoin, wasabi-wallet

Let's have 2 instances of wasabi wallet installed on different PCs. I have restored a wallet from a seed phrase on both of them and i can see all my coins on both of them.

I start coinjoin on one machine and after time - i have all coins coinjoined. Everything seems okay, i can spend it from the wallet instance that coinjoined them.

But the balance on the second instance becomes zero, and i can't see my coins. Restart does not help.

1. How can i restore coins in this situation?
2. How are keys for coinjoined coins generated?
3. Is it ok to transfer all this coins to one particular address to be able to restore them with a seed phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a key gap issue.
Try to increase the gap limit of the wallet to 1000.
https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/FAQ/FAQ-UseWasabi.html#how-do-i-change-the-gap-limit-of-a-wallet

> Is it ok to transfer all this coins to one particular address to be able to restore them with a seed phrase?

no. That is very bad for your privacy. If you would want to do something like this, you should do it in batches: multiple transfers and multiple (unused) addresses. However, avoid consolidating if possible.

Let us know if it works:)

Comment: Thank you! I thought of some kind of gap. I will try it

Comment: Great! I have done several experiments and it works perfect! Thank you a lot for your awesome advice!